# What book has a guy able to travel back in time to his childhood using a camcorder?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

I'm trying to find a book I read as a child in 2000 or 2001. It probably came out between 1990 and 2000.

I'm not 100% on the plot but as far as I remember the main character had had a traumatic experience where he and his friend fell through the ice on a lake while playing hockey. The main character survives but his friend does not.

Later on the boy figures out that he can travel back in time (or maybe just watch the past unfold) through this old camcorder of his. The main character then discovers what really happened on the ice and saves his friend's life, changing the future (his present).

The book also has these pages that are black with white text. This white text seems to be the voices or thoughts of some higher power beings who are looking out for the main character.

So far Google searches have failed me, I hope someone can help!

Comment: Is it a movie, or a book? The subject line says movie, the question body says book.

Comment: *The Butterfly Effect* is about a man with a traumatic childhood who can go back in time to change moments recorded in his journal or in pictures/movies.  There is a novelization of the movie.

Comment: I’m so glad I found this! I was just telling my husband about this book and I couldn’t remember any info on it. I’m years late but thanks for helping me find the answer!

Answer (score 7):

It could be "[Watchers: Rewind](http://www.openroadmedia.com/rewind)" by Peter Lerangis, the second book in [The Watchers](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50093-watchers) series.

> **A mysterious camera gives Adam the chance to change the past**
>
> *In the dead of a Vermont winter, Adam, Edgar, and Lianna skate onto the pond to practice hockey. Suddenly, a crack in the ice sends the
>   two boys tumbling into the frozen water. When he wakes up, Adam
>   remembers nothing—and his best friend is dead.*
>
> *Four years later, guilt haunts Adam. He and his friends are playing
>   laser tag near the pond when he stumbles over a backpack. Inside is a
>   video camera that lets him see into the past. Once he realizes its
>   power, Adam has a chance to learn what really happened that day on the
>   ice. But will the camera let him undo his mistake?*

[image: Watchers Book Cover]